# How to Implement Binding Validation for Binding Collection

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding, collections

I am new to WPF and having problem with validation of bound collection.

I have DataGrid that is bounded to collection of polymorphic objects that are grouped together.

The DataGrid has two columns:

- Lable oneTime bounded to the Display Name
- TextBox TwoWay bounded to the value when the TextBox LostFocus

Each line of the DataGrid is bounded to one object from the base class. Each derived class has its own validation method and I am trying to perform the appropriate validation method for the TextBox based on the instance of the derived class.

I can bind the validation based on the ExceptionValidationRule but the performances are not so well and the application blinks since it’s having a lot of exceptions. I also know that I can do that throw the event of the TextBox LostFocus and getting the source object but I am trying to use WPF validation for bounded objects if it’s possible.

I tried to inherit the ValidationRule in the base class and pass it but it’s enter with the base class to the function and not with the derived bounded item
I tried to create separate classes that implement the ValidationRule and DependencyObject and I am trying to pass to it the source object like explained here: http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2007/05/fully-binded-validation-by-using.html

But I still can’t make it to work. For the simplicity I created a DependencyObject that has TestString property and I tried to bind it to the Display Name (The bounded path of the Label). But the set of the TestString is never called.

How can I do that? How can I call the appropriate validation method? Can I pass the bounded object in some way to the Valuator?

Thanks for your help,
Sarit

The code I use:

Implementation class of DependencyObject:

```
class ManifestPropertyDependency : DependencyObject
{

    private ManifestProperty _manifestPropertyInstance;
    public ManifestProperty ManifestPropertyInstance
    {
        get { return (ManifestProperty)GetValue(ManifestPropertyInstanceProp); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ManifestPropertyInstanceProp, value);
        }
    }

    private string testString;
    public string TestString {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestStringProp); }
        set { SetValue(TestStringProp, value); }
    }
    public ManifestPropertyDependency()
    {
        testString = "";
        _manifestPropertyInstance = new ManifestProperty();
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ManifestPropertyInstanceProp =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ManifestPropertyInstance", typeof(ManifestProperty),
       typeof(ManifestPropertyDependency), new UIPropertyMetadata(new ManifestProperty()));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestStringProp =
       DependencyProperty.Register("TestString", typeof(string),
       typeof(ManifestPropertyDependency), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

Implementation class of ValidationRule:

```
class ManifestPropertyValidator : ValidationRule
{
    private ManifestProperty _manifest;
    private ManifestPropertyDependency _manifestPropertyDependency;
    public string Stam { get { return _manifestPropertyDependency.TestString; } set { _manifestPropertyDependency.TestString = value; } }
    public ManifestPropertyDependency ManifestPropertyDependency
    {
        get { return _manifestPropertyDependency; }


        set
        {
            _manifestPropertyDependency = value;
            Stam = value.TestString;
            _manifest = value.ManifestPropertyInstance;
        }
    }


    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            string errorMessage = "";
            if (ManifestPropertyDependency.ManifestPropertyInstance.ValidateString((string)value, ref errorMessage))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);
            }
            return new ValidationResult(false, errorMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters or " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The Xaml of the validation:

```
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" 
                                 Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBox}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay"  
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Classes:ManifestPropertyValidator>
                    <Classes:ManifestPropertyValidator.ManifestPropertyDependency>
                        <Classes:ManifestPropertyDependency TestString="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                    </Classes:ManifestPropertyValidator.ManifestPropertyDependency>
                </Classes:ManifestPropertyValidator> 
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: In class `ManifestPropertyDependency` you define backing fields `_manifestPropertyInstance` and `testString` for your dependency properties. This is wrong! DPs don't need backing fields. Their getters and setters call `DependencyObject.GetValue` and `DependencyObject.GetValue` instead (as you did). Assigning values to unused backing fields, as you do in the constructor, is pointless. Set the properties instead. And, when you use these DPs in XAML, WPF **will not** call the getter or setter, but access the underlying DP directly.

Comment: I know that the backing fields are not nessesary I did it's just for the debuging. I tried to realize what is going on in the DependencyObject. The get and set of the DependencyObject should be called from the ManifestPropertyValidator and I tried to see what I have inside this fields.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I couldnt underastand your code, but looking at your requirement, I find that this is simply the candidate for `IDataErrorInfo` interface.

Why are you not using that instead?

Also you talked about slowness in validation. Can you please elaborate on that? Is your template slow? Is your validation logic slow? Or do you think the validation notifications themselves are slow?

Comment: I tried to look the IDataErrorInfo but I don't understand how to use it. Who should implement the interface? should I rap the polymorphic object with a class that perform the IDataErrorInfo? Regarding the Slowness the application just keep blinking and not responsing after a while. I am supposing it's becouse of the exception validation since when I remove it the application works fine.

Comment: see this implementation... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation